# Required request body is missing in my PostRequest( to add a user to database)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

i created a controller to add a new user to the database
but when i tested the Post request in postman i got this error :

> {"code":null,"message":"Required request body is missing: public
>   com.pack.model.persistent.User
>   com.pack.restapi.controllers.UserController.create(com.model.persistent.User)"}

this is what did :

```js
//User class
@Entity
public class User extends PersistenceGenerique {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 245457152874587458468L;
 
 @Column
 @OrderBy
 private String firstname;

 @Column
 private String lastname;

 @Column
 private String email;

//service
public User create(User user);

//serviceIMPL

@Override
 public User create(User user) {
 userDao.persist(user);
 return user;
      }
        
//RestController
  @PostMapping
     public User create(@RequestBody User user){
         return userService.create(user);
     }
```

**EDIT**

Here is my typescript code for more details :

```js
    createUser(): void {
        this.usrSRV.CreateUser(this.user)
            .subscribe(data => {
                alert("User created successfully.");
            });

    };
```

```js
   CreateUser(user) {
        const userUrl = this._userUrl;        
        return this.http.post(userUrl, user)
            .map(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="createUser()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastname">LastName</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="lastname" placeholder="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">email</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Create user</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try with remove `@RequestBody`,if still not work then add your `javascript` code

Comment: it didn't work , u want me to add  my typescript code ?

Comment: yeah,add your code so that others can analysis it

Comment: i edited my code, you can check it now